# Rvest not scraping all instances from the webpage

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the names of products displayed on Etsy after searching for a specific term in the search bar.

The path to the product names I used is:

**"li.wt-list-unstyled .v2-listing-card__info h3"**

Checking it with SelectorGadget matches it with the 64 product names displayed.

Instead of 64 matched elements however, Rvest scrapes only the first 12 instances.

Moving through the pagination does not help insofar as that Rvest would be scraping the following 12 products, but just scrapes the top 12 on the new page again.

Included is an example of looking for cat toys:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.etsy.com/search?q=cat+toy&page=1&ref=pagination"
page <- read_html(link)


product_name <- page %>%
  html_nodes("li.wt-list-unstyled .v2-listing-card__info h3") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_trim()

length(product_name)
```

Running it returns only the names of the top 12 hits.

Comment: the others are probably dynamically loaded as you scroll on the page

Comment: It's very common for webpages to load data with javascript after they are opened in a browser. Note that `rvest` can only see the original source data, it cannot run javascript code. If you need to have a richer interaction with the page, you'll need a package like RSelenium instead to control a webbrowser for you.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll take a look into RSelenium, thanks!